# how do I get the data that was created in the last 24 hours or the last 30 days on laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

how do I get the data that was created in the last 24 hours or the last 30 days

```
            $last['last_trades'] = Credit::where
    ('user_id', $user->id)->where('description',
         '#1 Bonus Trade')->where('currency_code', 'LTC')->limit(5)->orderby
('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Specify the database name

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

...

$last['last_trades'] = Credit::where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->where('description', '#1 Bonus Trade')
    ->where('currency_code', 'LTC')
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->startOfDay())
    ->limit(5)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get()
```